# PyQt connecting signal between sub class and parent class

Tags: python, inheritance, pyqt5, qtgui, qt-signals

I want create a simple button to trigger some task. I was using PyQt designer to built GUI and trying to follow the advice that do not edit the UI module directly but put my customized code in a separate module then inherit all GUI aspects.

This is my GUI class:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(507, 424)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 350, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)


        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
```

This is my custom module:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore,QtGui,QtWidgets

# main.py is the GUI module
import main 


class mainWindow(mainTest.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        # I want click this button and print something
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.connectionTest)


    def connectionTest(self):
        print('connected')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = mainTest.Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Now my problem is when I run the module and click the pushbutton, it does not trigger the print method. However, if I directly add my custom code in GUI module it will work. I think there's something wrong with the inheritance and I do feel a bit confused about that.So what's the problem here?

Comment: change `MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()`
    `ui = mainTest.Ui_MainWindow()`
    `ui.setupUi(MainWindow)`
    `MainWindow.show()` to `w = mainWindow()` `w.show()`

Comment: You have created the mainWindow class but never use it .

Comment: also change to `class mainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, mainTest.Ui_MainWindow):`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using your `mainWindow` subclass at all, and even if you were, it should *also* inherit from QMainWindow.

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, mainTest.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        # ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Please note the *casing* I changed for the `MainWindow` class: it is standard convention to name all classes with Capitalized names, as only variables and functions should have lower cased names (read more on the official [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)).